Does COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED mean STA(Single Threaded Apartment)?
In WinAPI, CoInitializeEx requires dwCoInit parameter such as COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED or COINIT_MULTITHREADED.
The term "APARTMENTTHREADED" seems confusing as both STA (Single Threaded Apartment) or MTA (Multi Threaded Apartment) are apartments.
If COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED means STA, can anyone give official document that clarifies it?
AFAIK, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED is simply described as "Initializes the thread for apartment-threaded object concurrency".
It seems "COINIT_STA and COINIT_MTA" or "COINIT_SINGLETHREADED" and "COINIT_MULTITHREADED" delivers its meaning more precisely.

Yes, those constants would have been better, and Microsoft seems to agree: RoInitialize for the Windows Runtime uses RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED and RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED. But it's too late to change the constants for COM now.

Yes COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED is for STA, and COINIT_MULTITHREADED is for MTA.
The apparent discrepancy (missing the word "apartment" in the latter) is probably due to slight change in COM terminology over the years.
In any case you asked for some official documentation that confirms this, so here it is:

The documentation for Single-Threaded Apartments, explicitly mentions that COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED should be used with  CoInitializeEx.

The documentation for Multithreaded Apartments, explicitly mentions that COINIT_MULTITHREADED should be used with  CoInitializeEx.


Regarding:

It seems "COINIT_STA and COINIT_MTA" or "COINIT_SINGLETHREADED" and
"COINIT_MULTITHREADED" delivers its meaning more precisely.

That might be true, but since MS would like to maintain backwards compatibility it is problematic to change these identifier names (which are quite ancient, and widely used).
BTW - As @IInspectable commented above, MS seems to agree with you in principle, since for the newer RoInitialize API they chose identifier names along the lines of your suggestion: RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED, RO_INIT_MULTITHREADE.

Back in the days there was only CoInitialize https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize and so everything COM was only (implicitly) STA.

@SimonMourier wow that's really ancient history. I got acquainted with COM in the late nineties (~1998) and if I remember correctly CoInitializeEx was already available.

Yes, initially all RPC was through Windows messages (this is what you get with STA, still today) because Windows was not really in the general-purpose-machine-server business (that was really done by Office guys for Office) and then later on they added "real" RPC, what was called "DCOM" which doesn't need any Window (and allows machine to machine COM). There was even a "single" COM threading model (1 thread only for a whole process).
